# Make R report error on using non-existent column name in a data frame

Tags: r

In our usage of R for a non-trivial data analysis and estimation project, we've been repeatedly burnt by how tolerant R is toward misspelled or missing columns in a data frame. Typical example is calculating the weighted mean of a variable MYVAR in a data frame using another variable WEIGHT for weights:

```
m <- weighted.mean(tbl$MYVAR, w = tbl$WEIGHT, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Suppose I make a typo in the WEIGHT name in the operation above. What will happen in that R will expand my misspelled column into NULL and will use it for performing the weighted mean resulting in a non-weighted one.

Therefore, the question: is there any way to make R treat attempts to "read" a non-existent variables in a data frame as an error?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm... when I tried out your example with some fake data, `weighted.mean()` actually failed:

```
#Some fake data
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), weight = rnorm(100))

#The right weight var
weighted.mean(x = dat$x, w = dat$weight)
[1] 0.6161606

#Misspelled weight var
weighted.mean(x = dat$x, w = dat$wieght)
Error in weighted.mean.default(x = dat$x, w = dat$wieght) : 
  'x' and 'w' must have the same length
```

But anyway, another way to cope with this problem is to access your variables via indexing - it returns an error if you try to pick non-existant columns:

```
dat$wieght
NULL

dat[ , "wieght"]
Error in `[.data.frame`(dat, , "wieght") : undefined columns selected

weighted.mean(x = dat[ , "x"], w = dat[ , "wieght"], na.rm = TRUE)
Error in `[.data.frame`(dat, , "wieght") : undefined columns selected
```

Comment: Yes, this would definitely work but you have to admit that the syntax is somewhat unwieldy. dat[ , "WEIGHT"] is a lot less elegant compared to dat$WEIGHT.
I just wondered why there is no option to turn on the behavior above? This sounds like a very reasonable feature.

Comment: Also, on the heels of my last comment. I wonder if using attaching the data frame and then referencing the variables directly would mitigate this problem...

Comment: I would definitely avoid using attach in all circumstances, but I think that's the right idea.  You can use `with()` to attach a data frame for a single command: `with(dat, weighted.mean(x, weight, na.rm = TRUE))`.  Also, many functions like weighted.mean include a `data=` option that essentially internalizes this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you can enclose your code into try-catch blocks, see `?try` and the associated examples. It is easy to test for the class of the results ("try-error") in turn, e.g.

```
> res <- try(log("A"), silent=TRUE)
> class(res)
[1] "try-error"
```

You can also test directly for the correct spelling, by first listing the variables of interest--in your case, `MYVAR` and `WEIGHT`-- and test that they are part of the data.frame `df`, e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), g1=gl(2, 50), g2=gl(5,20))
sel.vars <- c("x","g2")
ifelse(all(sel.vars %in% colnames(df)), <compute things here>, "fail")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the snippet above would not help. Making sure that all columns (variables) are present in the data frame is one thing and it would never help against accidental misspelling of a variable name in some other corner of the code.